# Stripe checkout payment not available to pay out

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have a Stripe checkout page (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout) where customers can pay to providers. When I make a test payment, the money appears on the connected account's balance as `Total balance`, but it's not available to pay out (so `Available to pay out` amount is 0).

How can I make the money available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 4000000000000077 test card and the funds from any charges made on that test card will be immediately available.

https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses